# Using Key by Azure Key Vault to Encrypt and Decrypt text

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, rsa, azure-keyvault

I'm trying use a key from Azure Key Vault to Encrypt and Decrypt the cookies of a web API.

To encryption proccess I'm using the RSA, in that class:

```
    public class SimpleRSA
    {
        private RSA _rsa;

        public SimpleRSA(RSA rsa)
        {
            _rsa = rsa;
        }

        public string EncryptAsync(string value)
        {
            var byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
            var encryptedText = _rsa.Encrypt(byteData, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
            var encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedText);
            return encodedText;
        }


        public string DecryptAsync(string encryptedText)
        {
            var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            var decryptionResult = _rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
            var decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptionResult);
            return decryptedText;
        }
    }
```

And I'm getting my RSA from the Key, using that code:

```
  public RSA GetRSA(string appId, string appSecret)
        {
            AuthenticationCallback callback = async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

                var credential = new ClientCredential(appId, appSecret);
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
                return authResult.AccessToken;
            };

            var client = new KeyVaultClient(callback);

            var result = client.GetKeyAsync(_vaultBaseUrl, _keyId).Result;
            var key = result.Key;

            return key.ToRSA();
        }
```

I got the RSA from my Azure Key Vault and I managed encrypt my string. The problem is when I'm trying Decrypt the value. In that process I got that error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Error decoding OAEP padding.'
```

I think that can be happening because I'm without the private keys in RSA, but I've tried use this method to get the RSA with private key::

```
key.ToRSA(true);
```

[image]

But a got that error:

[image]

So, I don't know how I can complete this process. Are there other way to do that? Or what's wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use Azure Key Vault to Encrypt and Decrypt text, you can use SDK `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys` to implement it.

For example

1. Install SDK

```
Install-Package Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys -Version 4.0.3
Install-Package Azure.Identity -Version 1.1.1
```

2. Code

```
          ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, // your tenant id
                           clientId, // your AD application appId
                           clientSecret // your AD application app secret
                       );

            //get key
            var KeyVaultName = "<your kay vault name>";
            KeyClient keyClient = new KeyClient(new Uri($"https://{KeyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"), clientSecretCredential);;
            var keyName="<your key name>"
            var key = await keyClient.GetKeyAsync(keyName);

            // create CryptographyClient
            CryptographyClient cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(key.Value.Id, clientSecretCredential);

            var str ="test"
            Console.WriteLine("The String used to be encrypted is :  " +str );

            Console.WriteLine("-------------encrypt---------------");
            var byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
            var encryptResult = await cryptoClient.EncryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, byteData);
            var encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptResult.Ciphertext);
            Console.WriteLine(encodedText);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------dencrypt---------------");
            var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText);
            var dencryptResult = await cryptoClient.DecryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptedBytes);
            var decryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dencryptResult.Plaintext);
            Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);
```

[image]

Comment: @CaioSilvac Sorry  I cannot understand. Could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: I'm trying to use this to encrypt and decrypt cookies from a web API. So, I need to encrypt and decrypt my values locally. I can't do a request (using Decrypt Async) every time that I will need decrypt.

Comment: @CaioSilva Due to safety concerns,  Microsoft does not allow users to get Azure key vault key's private key with any method. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys#key-operations. So we cannot do decryption action on local. If you just want to do these on local, I suggest you create RSA key on premise then do these.

Comment: What permission is required to do this?  Key Vault Crypto User?

Comment: I could have marked this as an answer if I could :( Regrettably, I couldn't but it did solve my long-lasting answer to my question

Comment: @JimXu Please let us know why you selected `RsaOaep` over anything other?

Comment: Where do I get these : clientId, // your AD application appId
                           clientSecret // your AD application app secret. I only have Vault acess and it's shared by multiple applications

Answer (score 5):

Key Vault can store three item types: Keys, Secrets and Certificates. Keys are always asymmetric - RSA or Elliptic Curve, and the private keys don't leave KV. What you need is to use a symmetric key, but you need to store that as a Secret, not a key.

So store a 256-bit random secret in KV, call it MyCoolCryptoKey, pull that symmetric key into your C# code and use that as a key for AES.

Comment: That being said we need to use Azure KeyVault Secrets to store the AES key?
That make the encryption key less secured since it visible on Azure KeyVault.

How about of using RSA directly like this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/javascript-developer-guide-encrypt-decrypt-key#encrypt-and-decrypt-with-a-key